# Restarted initialization angular when updating DOM

Tags: angularjs

I have page:

```
<div>111</div><div id="123" ng-init='foo=555'>{{foo}}</div>
```

in browser:

```
111    
555
```

Code js refresh id=123 and get new html. I get:

```
<div id="123" ng-init='foo="444new"'><span>..</span><b>NEW TEXT<b> {{foo}}</div>
```

in browser

```
 111
 ...NEW TEXT {{foo}}
```

I want get in browser:

```
111
...NEW TEXT 444new
```

Is it possible to re-run the initialization angular in this situation?

DEMO: [jsfiddle.net/UwLQR](http://jsfiddle.net/UwLQR)

Solution for me: http://jsbin.com/iSUBOqa/8/edit - **this BAD PRACTICE!**

**UPD two months later:** My God, what nonsense I wrote. :(

Comment: Could you please create fiddle? It will be easier to help. Looks like you need to $scope.$apply or $compile.

Comment: hmm.. I use Yii - php framework and his $.fn.upgrade() - this upgrade DOM. In fiddle hard.

Comment: Create fiddle with thе exemplary situation - http://jsfiddle.net/UwLQR/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my notes in the included code and the [live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/iSUBOqa/1/edit)

The two reasons that angular will not register data-binding or directives are that the element isn't compiled, or the change happens outside of Angular. Using the $compile service, the `compile` function in directives, and `$scope.$apply` are the solutions. See below for usage.

**Sample markup:**

```
<div my-directive></div>
<div my-directive2></div>
<button id="bad-button">Bad Button!</button>
```

**Sample code:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.foo = '123!';
  $scope.bar = 'abc!';

  //this is bad practice! just to demonstrate!
  var badButton = document.getElementById('bad-button');
  badButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    //in here, the context is outside of angular, so use $apply to tell Angular about changes!
    $scope.$apply($scope.foo = "Foo is changed!");   
  });
});

app.directive('myDirective', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      //when using a link function, you must use $compile on the element
      var newElem = angular.element('<div>{{foo}}</div>');
      element.append(newElem);
      $compile(newElem)(scope);
      //or you can use:
      //$compile(element.contents())(scope);
    }

  };
});

app.directive('myDirective2', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    compile: function(element, attrs) {
      //compile functions don't have access to scope, but they automatically compile the element
      var newElem = angular.element('<div>{{bar}}</div>');
      element.append(newElem);
    }
  };
});
```

#### Update based on your comment

It makes me cringe to write this, but this is what you would need to make that code work.

```
var elem = document.getElementById('123');
elem.innerHTML = "<div ng-init=\"foo='qwe123'\">{{foo}}</div>";
$scope.$apply($compile(elem)($scope));
```

Just as I said, you need to compile the element AND, since that is in an event listener, you need to use `$apply` as well, so that Angular will know about the compile you're doing.

That said, if you're doing anything like this at all, you REALLY need to learn more about angular. Anything like that should be done via directives and NEVER with any direct DOM manipulation.

Comment: @EvgeniyTkachenko well, of course it doesn't work. What in the world are you doing that for??

Comment: @EvgeniyTkachenko see my updated answer, and please learn how to write Angular code the way it is intended.

Comment: i have Yii php and his js wrapper $fn.upgrade('123') - this upgrade DOM. I just did not want to rewrite this function on logic angulyar. There's no time.  I thought the launch of one row of some code decides this question. Thanks

Comment: @EvgeniyTkachenko I believe I answered your question very thoroughly. Why no accept?

Answer (score 1):

Try next:

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
  // your js updates here..
});
```

or

```
$compile('your html here')(scope);
```

Look [$compile example](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile) at bottom of page.